# Discrete random colors in plotly for large number of numeric categorical values so that close values have distinct colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, geopandas

I have a `geopandas` `dataframe` which has a `numeric categorical variable` such that this  variable has around 1500 categories. I'm plotting this data. my partly code is like:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(data_frame = df, ......... , color='numeric_categorical_variable', color_discrete_sequence = 'required-color_palette', ...........)
```

When I plot my data using `plotly` using any color palette available in `plotly` it assigns nearby values a visually same color due to a large number of numeric categories. Actually it assign sequential colors with slight difference but my eyes can not differentiate close colors.

Therefore, I'm looking for a color palette that has large number of random colors such that any close values in my `numeric categorical variable` will be assigned different distinct colors. I'm fine if any far distant values in my `numeric categorical variable` may have slightly same colors.
I've spent a lot of time on it but couldn't find the answer.

Comment: The fact  `"but my eyes can not differentiate close colors"`  leads to an important step before attempting to plot your data. You need to classify your data into small classes, then each class is assign the same symbol/color on your plot. You have 1500 different values (not called classes untill you classified them).

Comment: @swatchai I have 21216 values which has  around 1500 unique values and I want  a distinct color for each of 1500+ categories.